# Unable to show steps in Wizard control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a flow on my site using a Wizard & Multiview.   To give some background what I want is that a user goes to a page, that page will display one of the Views contained in the first ActiveStep in the Wizard.   This will be calculated using certain information that I will already have on the user, we'll call the Views Option 1 and Option 2.

From Option 1 or 2 I want there to be a button (Next at the bottom of the mark-up posted below) that will move onto Step 2 of the Wizard.    What I'm struggling with so far is that when the page loads the ActiveStep in the Wizard and the View are both null causing an exception, so I'm wondering how this actually gets initialised?  I know for the Views if I remove that mark-up and place it outside the Wizard, then it works fine, but it doesn't work contained in another control.    I'm hoping once I actually get the page loading everything else will slip into place.

```
<asp:Wizard ID="optionsWizard" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" Width="100%" FinishCompleteButtonText="Submit" OnFinishButtonClick="optionsWizard_FinishButtonClick"
    StepPreviousButtonText="Previous" OnNextButtonClick="optionsWizard_NextButtonClick">
    <asp:WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="wsoptionsMaintenance" runat="server" Title="<div class='active'>Step 1</div><div>Step 2</div>" OnActivate="wsoptionsMaintenance_Activate">
            <asp:MultiView ID="mvoptions" runat="server">
                <asp:View ID="vwActivate" runat="server">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnloptionsActivation" runat="server">
                        <fieldset>
                            <span class="legend">Option 1</span>
                            <div class="wholeFormEntryContainer">
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlActivateNewoptions" runat="server" CssClass="formEntryContainer">
                                    <p>
                                        Some text for option 1
                                    </p>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlRequestNewoptions" runat="server" CssClass="formEntryContainer">
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="vwReplace" runat="server">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrderGridCard" runat="server">
                        <fieldset>
                            <span class="legend">Option 2</span>
                            <div class="wholeFormEntryContainer">
                                <p>
                                    Some text for option 2                                      
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView>
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="wsRegisteroptions" runat="server" Title="<div>Step 1</div><div class='active'>Step 2</div>">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnloptionsRegistration" runat="server">
                <fieldset>
                    <span class="legend">Option Register</span>

                    <div class="wholeFormEntryContainer">
                        <p>
                            Text for registering options.
                        </p>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername" Width="250" /><p></p>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" Width="250" />
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </asp:WizardSteps>


    <StartNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext"
            Text="Next" CssClass="btnNext floatRight" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnLoginCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnLoginCancel_Click"
            CssClass="btnCancel floatRight" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="cancel" />
    </StartNavigationTemplate>
    <StepNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext"
            Text="Next" CssClass="btnNext floatRight" />
    </StepNavigationTemplate>
    <FinishNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" CommandName="MoveComplete"
            CssClass="btnContinue floatRight" Text="Next" />
    </FinishNavigationTemplate>
</asp:Wizard>
```

In terms of the backend code, here is a walk through of what happens:

The page loads, the ActiveStepIndex is -1 but it shows 0 steps available, even though there are two in the mark-up.    Mvoptions is currently null.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        optionsWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 1;  // Throws exception as there are 0 Steps in the Wizard
         if (mvOptionView != null)
         {
                // Do some stuff, but it never comes in here as it is null
         }
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint on optionsWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 1 and skip it then the processing will continue into the Page_PreRender.  At this stage it fires another exception and the page will fail.

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (optionsWizard.ActiveStep.ID)  // Null reference exception thrown, ActiveStep is null
        {
        }
    }
```

Hopefully I haven't waffled too much, if I need to provide any more info I'll gladly do it.

Answer (score 0):

> with so far is that when the page loads the ActiveStep in the Wizard
>   and the View are both null causing an exception

add stepType=Start to first View like

```
 <asp:WizardStep ID="wsoptionsMaintenance" runat="server" Title="<div class='active'>Step 1</div><div>Step 2</div>" OnActivate="wsoptionsMaintenance_Activate" StepType="Start">
```

Comment: OK just tried that, it still gives the same result.  A 0 count for the number of Steps on the Wizard property.